# Please explain my logical error while parsing .html files using basic Python

Tags: python, html, arrays, string, parsing

I have a script which runs and should produce a number of new .html files within a directory. It exits with code 0 indicating no issues and as far as I can tell SHOULD work correctly. It doesn't though! :)

The code should iterate over a directory of .html files and find all of the text between two elements in a HTML file (these elements are stored in the variables start and end).

```
import os

dir = os.listdir("C:/Users/folder")

files = []

for file in dir:
    if file[-5:] == '.html':
        files.insert(0, file)


for fileName in files:
    print fileName
    file = open("C:/Users/folder/" + fileName)
    content = file.read()
    file.close()

    start = content.find('<div class="title">')
    end = content.find('<div class="footer">')

    if start != -1:
        newContent = content[start:]
    if end != -1:
        newContent = content[0:end - 1]

    file = open(fileName + "_mod", 'w')
    file.write(newContent)
    file.close()
```

So this should iterate over a directory, find the text between `'<div class="title">'` and `'<div class="footer">'`, save this text in a variable which is put into a new file which has the same name as the original with "_mod" appended to the end.

This not how it behaves, however. Instead, it finds from the beginning of the document up until the footer div.

So I want it to convert a given html file from :

```
<head>
   <title>This is bad HTML</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1> Remove me</h1>
  <div class="title">
    <h1> This is the good data, keep me</h1>

    <p> Keep this text </p>

  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <h1> Remove me, I am pointless</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```

Into just :

```
  <div class="title">
    <h1> This is the good data, keep me</h1>

    <p> Keep this text </p>

  </div>
```

But the output I am currently getting is :

```
<head>
   <title>This is bad HTML</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1> Remove me</h1>
  <div class="title">
    <h1> This is the good data, keep me</h1>

    <p> Keep this text </p>

  </div>
```

What logical errors have I made here?

Comment: `if end != -1: newContent = content[0:end - 1]` ... what do you think this does, exactly?

Comment: @l4mpi If the text is found then  into the newContent variable add all of the content from the beginning of content until the point where the text is found, -1.

Comment: You want `newContent = content[start:end]`. BTW, there are better ways to parse HTML (look up BeautifulSoup)

Comment: See also http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: If I may add to the resources provided by @jonrsharpe - [How to be a Programmer](http://samizdat.mines.edu/howto/HowToBeAProgrammer.html).  The first section is [Learn to Debug](http://samizdat.mines.edu/howto/HowToBeAProgrammer.html#id2790282) which begins: "Debugging is the cornerstone of being a programmer. The first meaning of the verb to debug is to remove errors, but the meaning that really matters is to see into the execution of a program by examining it. A programmer that cannot debug effectively is blind."

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the poster is not actually interested in any of the advice given them.  Valid questions on StackOverflow must be sincere attempts to solve a practical programming problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your flaw lies in:

```
if start != -1:
    newContent = content[start:]
if end != -1:
    newContent = content[0:end - 1]
```

if `start!=-1` and `end != -1`, newContent will only be `content[0:end - 1]`

You could do something like

```
start = start if (start != -1) else 0
end = end if (end != -1) else len(content)
```

and then

```
newContent = content[start:end -1]
```

Comment: This code returns only the start and end divs with none of the content in between for some reason I cannot even begin to fathom! :)